# Connect to RDS Postgress db with IAM role permission in vertx.io

Tags: amazon-iam, vert.x

I have a dockerized kotlin app, using vertx.io running in the AWS environment. I'd like it to be use its IAM credentials to login to the DB. I am using this code to generate a password:

`val generator: RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator = RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator.builder()
.credentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
.region(region)
.build()

```
            dbPassword = generator.getAuthToken(
                GetIamAuthTokenRequest.builder()
                    .hostname(dbHost)
                    .port(dbPort.toInt())
                    .userName(dbUser)
                    .build()`
```

I was able to login with the password here to my DB via SQL editor so I know this works.
I'm using this code in an attempt to connect to the db:
`val connectOptions = PgConnectOptions()
.setPort(dbPort)
.setHost(dbHost)
.setDatabase(dbName)
.setUser(dbUser)
.setPassword(dbPassword)

```
        // Pool options
        val poolOptions = PoolOptions()
            .setMaxSize(dbMaxConnections)

        // Create the client pool
        pgPool = PgPool.pool(vertx, connectOptions, poolOptions)`
```

This passes but when I actually attempt to access the DB. It results in Timeout.
What am I missing